# Set up Jmeter proxy for curl commands

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm new to JMeter and I want to test performance of api and  recording test case with JMeter proxy.

I've first followed instruction here http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf and all worked fine.

I am calling this api using curl commands. Question is how to set up proxy for that requests are recorded in the JMeter when running curl commands

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty easy to just rewrite the same requests in Jmeter, if you have a script ready.
Anyway, cUrl has a proxy option.

```
 -x, --proxy <[protocol://][user:password@]proxyhost[:port]>

      Use the specified HTTP proxy. 
      If the port number is not specified, it is assumed at port 1080.
```

You can set it to the Jmeter proxy.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I did not get this. I can easily set up a proxy server for mozilla using below two steps  1. Install jmeter certificate in Mozilla   2. In the Network settings in mozilla , choose manual proxy settings set as Http Proxy:"localhost" and PortNumber:8080. I do not require any username password to do this. How can the same be done with culr.

Comment: protocol, user, password and port are optional. in your case you will need to add to each curl `-x http://localhost:8080`

Comment: thanks for your help , but all my api calls are using https . When I use http it does get recorded in jmeter but how to record https call

Comment: This answer saved my day